# Variable from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

I'm creating a function (mother) javascript that goes inside to call another function (ajax).
The ajax function sends the data to an asp page
The answer I need inside then the function mother

to call the function ajax so I write (in the function mother)

```
                  prendoDato=sendRequest(url,handleRequest);
                  alert(" prendoDato  " + prendoDato)
```

while the function is this ajax

```
   function handleRequest(req) {
   }

   function sendRequest(url,callback,postData) {
       var req = createXMLHTTPObject();
       if (!req) return;
       var method = (postData) ? "POST" : "GET";
       req.open(method,url,true);


     req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       if (postData)
           req.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
       req.onreadystatechange = function () {
           alert('HTTP error ' + req.status);
           if (req.readyState != 4) return;
           if (req.status != 200 && req.status != 304) {
          //          alert('HTTP error ' + req.status);
               return;
           }
           if (req.status == 200)
           {
               alert("req " +req.responseText)
               return req.responseText
           }
           callback(req);

       }
       if (req.readyState == 4) return;
       req.send(postData);
          }


          var XMLHttpFactories = [
       function () {return new XMLHttpRequest()},
       function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")},
       function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml3.XMLHTTP")},
       function () {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}
   ];


   function createXMLHTTPObject() {
       var xmlhttp = false;
       for (var i=0;i<XMLHttpFactories.length;i++) {
           try {
               xmlhttp = XMLHttpFactories[i]();
           }
           catch (e) {
               continue;
           }
           break;
       }
       return xmlhttp;
   }
```

the problem I have is this:
I call the function ajax
and I would put the return value in a variable in the function mother
the problem and that the ajax function but passes the value to the variable undefined
to make sure I put the alert and practically
I get the first alert that is after the function call ajax
and then the alerts that are in the ajax function, after which intercepts the value, but that is no longer able to pass it to the variable prendoDato

I tried to put a do loop in the function mother, but goes in a continuous loop

```
  do {

            cccc=sendRequest(url,handleRequest);
            alert("cccc "+cccc)
        }
        while (cccc !== "undefined");
```

Comment: *"I tried to put a mother in the function cycle"*... Whaatt??

Comment: I tried to put a do loop in the function mother, but goes in a continuous loop
<code>   do {
                
                cccc=sendRequest(url,handleRequest);
                alert("cccc "+cccc)
            }
            while (cccc !== "undefined");
</code>

Answer (score -1):

problem solved

because of an asynchronous request

I settled with a callback

place below the function and how the call

```
function call_ajax(urlPage,postdata){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: urlPage,
    dataType: "html",
    data: postdata,
    async: false,
    cache: false, 
    timeout:30000,
    success: function(html){
    //alert("html " + html);
    //return html

    obj = html


    }
    });


    if(obj =='"empty"'){
    return false;
    }else{
    return obj;
    }

    }






    url="/include/ajaxTempoDistanza.asp"
    postData="origine=43.608896,3.880175&destintario=4.60736,3.8939890000000332&stampa=no"  

    sp=call_ajax(url,postData)
    alert(" sp " + sp)
```